# How to compare two dataframes with dates, return matching dates and tag non-matching dates for each row in new dataframe

Tags: r, date

I have a dateframe with multiple measuring dates for each subjects in each row, and another dataframe with multiple visit dates for the same subject in each row (also including some NA's).

What I want is to extract the measuring dates that match the visit dates for a certain subject, and tag the measuring dates that do not comply a visit date (e.g, with a 'FALSE' or -99), and keep the NA's as is.

```
set.seed(1)

# Dataframe with measure dates
df1 <- rbind.data.frame(sort(sample(seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-01"), by = "day"), 10)),
                        c(sort(sample(seq(as.Date("2018-06-01"), as.Date("2019-06-01"), by = "day"), 8)), NA, NA),
                        c(sort(sample(seq(as.Date("2019-06-01"), as.Date("2020-06-01"), by = "day"), 6)), rep(NA, 4)))
names(df1) <- paste("MEASUREDATE", 1:10, sep = "")

myfun <- function(x) as.Date(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = "1970-01-01")
df1 <- data.frame(lapply(df1, myfun))
df1

# Dataframe with visit dates
df2 <- rbind.data.frame(as.numeric(df1[1, 2:7]), as.numeric(c(df1[2, 4:6], NA, NA, NA)), as.numeric(c(df1[3, 1:2], rep(NA, 4))))
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df2, myfun))
names(df2) <- paste("VISIT", 1:6, sep = "")
df2
```

So the fist row of the new dataframe would be like this:

```
# New dataframe
df3 <- df1[1, ]
df3[1] <- FALSE
df3[8:10] <- FALSE
df3
```

Do you know how to tackle this problem? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I just realized that you wanted to distinguish between `NA` and `FALSE`. I have updated my answer so that these can be separate, rather than returning all NAs.

Comment: Nice catch @AndrewGillreath-Brown, have updated mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to work with both dataframes in long format. Here, I pivot `df1` long, then I `left_join` to `df2` (also after converting it to a long format). For dates that have a match, the name from `df2` will be present (while others will be `NA`), then we can use this information to convert the date data to `NA` if there is no match. Then, I drop the column `name.y` that had the visit number, and keep only unique values. Then, we can pivot back to the wider format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  left_join(.,
            df2 %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
              pivot_longer(-row),
            by = c("row", "value")) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(is.na(name.y)
                           ~ as.Date(NA),
                           TRUE ~ value)) %>%
  select(-name.y) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name.x", values_from = "value") %>% 
  select(-row)
```

**Output**

```
  MEASUREDATE1 MEASUREDATE2 MEASUREDATE3 MEASUREDATE4 MEASUREDATE5 MEASUREDATE6 MEASUREDATE7 MEASUREDATE8 MEASUREDATE9 MEASUREDATE10
  <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       
1 NA           2018-05-09   2018-06-16   2018-07-06   2018-09-27   2018-10-04   2018-10-26   NA           NA           NA           
2 NA           NA           NA           2018-11-12   2018-12-30   2019-01-03   NA           NA           NA           NA           
3 2019-08-28   2020-03-15   NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
```

**Update**

If you want to distinguish between `FALSE` and `NA`, then we will need to convert `date` to `character` first. Then, we can set some additional conditions in `case_when`.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  left_join(.,
            df2 %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
              pivot_longer(-row),
            by = c("row", "value")) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.character(.))) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(is.na(name.y) & !is.na(value) ~ "FALSE",
                           !is.na(name.y) & !is.na(value) ~ value,
                           TRUE ~ "NA")) %>%
  select(-name.y) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name.x", values_from = "value") %>% 
  select(-row)
```

**Output**

```
  MEASUREDATE1 MEASUREDATE2 MEASUREDATE3 MEASUREDATE4 MEASUREDATE5 MEASUREDATE6 MEASUREDATE7 MEASUREDATE8 MEASUREDATE9 MEASUREDATE10
  <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        
1 FALSE        2018-05-09   2018-06-16   2018-07-06   2018-09-27   2018-10-04   2018-10-26   FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        
2 FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        2018-11-12   2018-12-30   2019-01-03   FALSE        FALSE        NA           NA           
3 2019-08-28   2020-03-15   FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        NA           NA           NA           NA
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    MEASUREDATE1 = structure(c(17616, 17719, 18136), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE2 = structure(c(17660, 17761, 18336), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE3 = structure(c(17698, 17787, 18337), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE4 = structure(c(17718, 17847, 18373), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE5 = structure(c(17801, 17895, 18387), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE6 = structure(c(17808, 17899, 18409), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE7 = structure(c(17830, 17945, NA), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE8 = structure(c(17838, 18011, NA), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE9 = structure(c(17855, NA, NA), class = "Date"),
    MEASUREDATE10 = structure(c(17861, NA, NA), class = "Date")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-3L)
)

df2 <-
  structure(
    list(
      VISIT1 = structure(c(17660, 17847, 18136), class = "Date"),
      VISIT2 = structure(c(17698, 17895, 18336), class = "Date"),
      VISIT3 = structure(c(17718, 17899, NA), class = "Date"),
      VISIT4 = structure(c(17801, NA, NA), class = "Date"),
      VISIT5 = structure(c(17808, NA, NA), class = "Date"),
      VISIT6 = structure(c(17830, NA, NA), class = "Date")
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-3L)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your most helpful replies. They are very much appreciated. @Andrew Gillreath-Brown, your answer worked wonderfully. If I would want to skip converting the resulting dataframe back into a wide format, what tidyverse code can remove from your answer (as I am not familiar with this package)?

Comment: @Orangemarmalade No problem! If you want to keep in long format, then you can just delete the `pivot_wider` line towards the bottom of the code. Also, just FYI, `tidyverse` loads several packages all at once. Here, I am really just using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest way is to take the nice long route that @Andrew Gillreath-Brown's answer provides. However, if you desire, we can also just simply apply across the rows of the data frames (if `nrow(df1) == nrow(df2)`).

```r
dfl <- lapply(
  1:nrow(df1),
  \(i) {
    measures <- as.Date(unlist(df1[i,]), origin = "1970-01-01")
    visits <- as.Date(unlist(df2[i,]), origin = "1970-01-01")
    measures[!(measures %in% visits)] <- NA
    measures
  } 
)

dfl
#> [[1]]
#>  MEASUREDATE1  MEASUREDATE2  MEASUREDATE3  MEASUREDATE4  MEASUREDATE5 
#>            NA  "2018-05-09"  "2018-06-16"  "2018-07-06"  "2018-09-27" 
#>  MEASUREDATE6  MEASUREDATE7  MEASUREDATE8  MEASUREDATE9 MEASUREDATE10 
#>  "2018-10-04"  "2018-10-26"            NA            NA            NA 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  MEASUREDATE1  MEASUREDATE2  MEASUREDATE3  MEASUREDATE4  MEASUREDATE5 
#>            NA            NA            NA  "2018-11-12"  "2018-12-30" 
#>  MEASUREDATE6  MEASUREDATE7  MEASUREDATE8  MEASUREDATE9 MEASUREDATE10 
#>  "2019-01-03"            NA            NA            NA            NA 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  MEASUREDATE1  MEASUREDATE2  MEASUREDATE3  MEASUREDATE4  MEASUREDATE5 
#>  "2019-08-28"  "2020-03-15"            NA            NA            NA 
#>  MEASUREDATE6  MEASUREDATE7  MEASUREDATE8  MEASUREDATE9 MEASUREDATE10 
#>            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
```

Then for convenience can just bind together to get your `df3` (or just use `purrr::map_dfr` above).

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(dfl)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 10
#>   MEASUREDATE1 MEASUREDATE2 MEASUREDATE3 MEASUREDATE4 MEASUREDATE5 MEASUREDATE6
#>   <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>      
#> 1 NA           2018-05-09   2018-06-16   2018-07-06   2018-09-27   2018-10-04  
#> 2 NA           NA           NA           2018-11-12   2018-12-30   2019-01-03  
#> 3 2019-08-28   2020-03-15   NA           NA           NA           NA          
#> # … with 4 more variables: MEASUREDATE7 <date>, MEASUREDATE8 <date>,
#> #   MEASUREDATE9 <date>, MEASUREDATE10 <date>
```

#### Update

@Andrew Gillreath-Brown noted you want to keep `FALSE` and `NA` separate. If you want to keep the `FALSE` and `NA` values separate, then just convert the strings to characters first with this method.

```r
dfl2 <- lapply(
  1:nrow(df1),
  \(i) {
    measures <- as.character(as.Date(unlist(df1[i,]), origin = "1970-01-01"))
    visits <- as.character(as.Date(unlist(df2[i,]), origin = "1970-01-01"))
    measures[!(measures %in% visits)] <- "FALSE"
    measures
  } 
)

dplyr::bind_rows(dfl2)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 10
#>   MEASUREDATE1 MEASUREDATE2 MEASUREDATE3 MEASUREDATE4 MEASUREDATE5 MEASUREDATE6
#>   <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 FALSE        2018-05-09   2018-06-16   2018-07-06   2018-09-27   2018-10-04  
#> 2 FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        2018-11-12   2018-12-30   2019-01-03  
#> 3 2019-08-28   2020-03-15   FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE       
#> # … with 4 more variables: MEASUREDATE7 <chr>, MEASUREDATE8 <chr>,
#> #   MEASUREDATE9 <chr>, MEASUREDATE10 <chr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your most helpful replies. They are very much appreciated. @caldwellst, I very much like that your answer is coded with base R. However, when I run your code I stumble upon an error. The \ seems to be an unexpected input. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah, that's from R >= 4.1, `\(x)` is shorthand for `function(x)`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your support. Very much appreciated.